# what is --limit 5/s meaning?

Tags: iptables

i need explanation for what time meaning on this rule of `iptables`

```
iptables -N udp-flood
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -j udp-flood
iptables -A udp-flood -p udp -m limit --limit 5/s -j RETURN
iptables -A udp-flood -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix 'UDP-flood attempt: '
iptables -A udp-flood -j DROP
iptables -A udp-flood -p udp -m limit --limit 5/second --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
iptables -A udp-flood -p udp -j DROP
```

i mean on this two line

```
iptables -A udp-flood -p udp -m limit --limit 5/s -j RETURN

iptables -A udp-flood -p udp -m limit --limit 5/second --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
```

what happen if i set it to `60/s` or `60/second` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used to restrict the rate of matches, such as for suppressing log messages. It will only match a given number of times per second (by default 3 matches per hour, with a burst of 5). It takes two optional arguments:

--limit

```
followed by a number; specifies the maximum average number of matches to allow per second. The number can specify units explicitly, using `/second', `/minute', `/hour' or `/day', or parts of them (so `5/second' is the same as `5/s').
```

--limit-burst

```
followed by a number, indicating the maximum burst before the above limit kicks in.
```

This may help you more, http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html